# Derive the joint probability density function of differences of Gaussian Mixtures

Tags: probability, distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Consider a 3-variate random vector $(\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ which is distributed as a Gaussian mixture: (with some abuse of notation)
$$
f(\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)=\underbrace{w_a \mathcal{N}\Big(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_a\\
\mu_a\\
\mu_a
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_a & \rho_a & \rho_a\\
 \rho_a &\sigma^2_a &  \rho_a\\
\rho_a & \rho_a &\sigma^2_a \\
\end{pmatrix}\Big)}_{\text{component (a)}} +\underbrace{w_b\mathcal{N}\Big(\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_b\\
\mu_b\\
\mu_b
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_b & \rho_b & \rho_b\\
 \rho_b &\sigma^2_b &  \rho_b\\
\rho_b & \rho_b &\sigma^2_b \\
\end{pmatrix}\Big)}_{\text{component (b)}}
$$
where $f$ denotes the PDF, $(w_a, w_b)$ are the mixture weights, $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ stays for 3-variate normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and var-cov matrix $\Sigma$.

Is it possible to derive $f(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)$? If yes, could you walk me through the derivation?

I'm confused on how to proceed:

- Deriving the (marginal) PDF of $(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0)$ and $(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2)$ when $\{\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$ are mutually independent is explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174791/sum-of-gaussian-mixture-and-gaussian-scale-mixture) for example.
- Here, however, I don't have mutual independence. Moreover, I want the joint of pairs of differences.

Any hint would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry when I try to answer you question it was mixed up. Could you try to recover to your original question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left (\begin{matrix} \epsilon_1-\epsilon_0 \\ \epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\end{matrix}\right) = \left (\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1& 0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right)\left (\begin{matrix} \epsilon_0 \\  \epsilon_1\\\epsilon_2\end{matrix}\right) = A\epsilon$

Then $$f(\epsilon_0-\epsilon_1, \epsilon_0-\epsilon_2)=\underbrace{w_a \mathcal{N}\Big(A\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_a\\
\mu_a\\
\mu_a
\end{pmatrix}, A\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_a & \rho_a & \rho_a\\
 \rho_a &\sigma^2_a &  \rho_a\\
\rho_a & \rho_a &\sigma^2_a \\
\end{pmatrix}A'\Big)}_{\text{component (a)}} +\underbrace{w_b\mathcal{N}\Big(A\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_b\\
\mu_b\\
\mu_b
\end{pmatrix}, A\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_b & \rho_b & \rho_b\\
 \rho_b &\sigma^2_b &  \rho_b\\
\rho_b & \rho_b &\sigma^2_b \\
\end{pmatrix}A'\Big)}_{\text{component (b)}}
$$

Comment: is $A'$ inside the brackets?

Comment: I have another question on the Gaussian mixture in case you may have time https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374834/distribution-of-difference-of-gaussian-mixtures-symmetric-wrto-zero

Comment: Yes, edited, put A inside.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your mixture correctly. If you think my understanding for this question is correct, I will go to your other similar questions.

Comment: Thanks. 1) I think to have $A$ as you define the vector of epsilons should be ordered $(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_0, \epsilon_2)$. 2) I'm confused about the way you work with mixtures: according to your methodology, for example, $f(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0)=w_a \mathcal{N}(0, 2(\sigma^2_a-\rho_a))+w_b \mathcal{N}(0, 2(\sigma^2_b-\rho_b))$.

Comment: Let's try to replicate this last result on $f(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0)$ through another procedure: $f(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_0, \epsilon_2)=w_a \mathcal{N}(...)+w_b \mathcal{N}(...)$ implies that $f(\epsilon_1)=w_a \mathcal{N}(\mu_a, \sigma^2_a)+w_b \mathcal{N}(\mu_b, \sigma^2_b)$ and $f(-\epsilon_0)=w_a \mathcal{N}(-\mu_a, \sigma^2_a)+w_b \mathcal{N}(-\mu_b, \sigma^2_b)$. Now, according to this answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174791/sum-of-gaussian-mixture-and-gaussian-scale-mixture, $f(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0)$ should be a mixture of 4 components (when $\rho_a=\rho_b=0$).

Comment: Why instead $f(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_0)$ is a mixture of only 2 components according to your procedure?